# Determine if a Cloudfetch connection is used or not in Databricks

Tags: databricks

I try to see if a cloudfetch connection is in use or not. I have configure my DBR cluster to allow cloudfetch. When I run a job and if the response is big enough, over 1MB, it should use cloudfetch.
If cloudfetch is used it will store the response in the root bucket for the workspace. In my case this bucket is chaos and I have a hard time to navigate it. Does anyone know the more exact path that will be created for cloudfetch results?

Answer (score 0):

The Correct path for (in my case) was:

```
workspace_rootbucket/region_folder/workspaceid.jobs/sql/date/nr/
```

Due to that this is created I can be sure that Cloudfetch is working.